# efficient counter to count incorrect input attempt from text file in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am making a program that reads a text file that has logged values of incorrect input attempts (whether it's 'password < 6' or 'password > 10' characters). The program prints the list horizontally and makes it quite long so I wanted to make it vertical for easier read but I don't know how to. Also, for every log (password < 6 or password > 10), I was hoping to make a counter which states how many times the statements have occurred in the log file and again I don't really know how to do it.

Here's the code:

```py
def main():
    with open("ITWorks_password_log.txt", "r") as ITWorks_password_log:
        lines = ITWorks_password_log.readlines()

    time = []
    pass_characters = []

    for l in lines:
        as_list = l.split(", ")
        time.append(as_list[0])
        pass_characters.append(as_list[1].replace("\n", ""))

    count_pw_too_small = "password < 6"
    count_pw_too_large = "password > 10"

    print(time)
    print(pass_characters)


main()
```

1: Sample of Text File

```
2021-07-22 16:24:42.843103, password < 6
2021-07-22 16:24:44.963020, password < 6
2021-07-22 16:24:49.327202, password > 10
2021-07-22 16:24:52.810838, password > 10
2021-07-22 16:24:57.057562, password > 10
2021-07-22 16:24:58.961836, password < 6
```

2. Envisioned Output
   Two brackets with time and incorrect attempt label
   total count for attempts lower than 6 characters
   total count for attempts higher than 10 characters

Comment: Can you show a sample of your input file and what you expect the output to be?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or text. See [here](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) for more info

Comment: Sure, I have added two images, with image 1 being a snippet of the text file and 2 being the end output I envision.

Comment: @DevP as noted above, I'd suggest [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69761686/edit) the question to format the text into it.

Comment: Note that I generally use triple backticks around text ``` and don't have to indent each line. I'm not sure if there's an easier way actually.

Comment: I have made the changes in the edit, can you have a look now? Thanks

Comment: The "in" operate seems obvious for the string comparison. collections.Counter comes to mind, but you'd iterate over the list twice. Do you need to keep the list at all? That seems like a lot of wasted space, if you just want the counts.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty much, "just do it" for a lot of these questions, but since you did post a good bit of code, I'll suggest an alternative for your data structure. Store all the reasons in a dict, as you parse each line. I used defaultdict merely for convenience.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def main(inputfile):
    with open(inputfile, "r") as f:
        results = defaultdict(list)
        for line in f.readlines():
            timestamp, reason = line.strip().split(", ")
            # you should probably read the timestamp into an actual datetime object here
            results[reason].append(timestamp)
        
        for reason, timestamps in results.items():
            print ('The reason "{}" occurred {} times.'.format(reason, len(timestamps)))

main("ITWorks_password_log.txt")
```

> The reason "password < 6" occurred 3 times.
> The reason "password > 10" occurred 3 times.

Of course, if you only care about the counts, you do not need the individual timestamps. You can just store the count in a dict or defaultdict(int).

If you do want to keep all the data in a collection, then you can pass that collection to collections.Counter to get a similar result, with the downside that you'd iterate over the whole list a second time-uh. But that's not such a big deal. Here's an example with collections.Counter, but not keeping the data:

```
from collections import Counter

def records(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            timestamp, reason = line.split(",")
            yield reason.strip()

def main(filename):
    counter = Counter(records(filename))
    print(counter)

main("ITWorks_password_log.txt")
```

> Counter({'password < 6': 3, 'password > 10': 3})